# Power BI Embedded - Data refresh on "Import" mode

Tags: azure, powerbi

I would like to know how Power BI Embedded support data refresh, or schedule to refresh data like Power BI service on "Import" mode, I am not using Direct Query.

Also, does Power BI embedded has file size limitation 250M like power BI service in "Import" mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [What is Microsoft Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-what-is-power-bi-embedded/), data refresh is not supported:

> Cached datasets can be used in Preview. However, you cannot refresh cached data once it has been loaded into Microsoft Power BI Embedded.

According to [Connecting to a data source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-connect-datasource/), only DirectQuery is supported:

> With Power BI Embedded, you can embed reports into your own app. When you embed a Power BI report into your app, the report connects to the underlying data by importing a copy of the data or connecting directly to the data source using DirectQuery.

I believe Power BI Embedded has the same 250 MB limitation for import.

Comment: Do you know when Power BI releases this feature, It's crucial, though.

Comment: John, where exactly does the 250 MB limitation apply to? The size of the .PBIX file?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar I think the 250 MB limitation applies to the dataset size.